# Duplicate and Align collection

Tags: 3d-view, collections, duplicate

[image]

In the image above, I have a small light bulb on the floor, every mesh regarding that lightbulb is parented to the glass head, then it's all in LOWER BULB collection.

- I want to duplicate and arrange the light bulb such that there's like 20+ of it on the floor.
- I have tried to duplicate the collection and arrange them one after the other, but it's time consuming and tiring.
- Is there an easy way I can go about it?

(I'm not confident about the title of the question. If it can be edited for better understanding, please do)

Answer (score 1):

You can use geometry nodes. From what I understand you just want to distribute copies of the glassbulb collection on the floor. [image]

(In his setup I have added the selection to the distribute points on faces node because the surface you want to distribute on also extent to the background wall. Other wise this is not needed. So in this setup any face that has a value of 1 in the z-component of the normal is selected.(Please make sure that the face orientation is correct, if not go to edit mode and click alt+n and flip faces) Next points are distributed on the face. Then on these points the instances from the collection info node are instanced. (In the transform geometry node you will have to reset the location of the collection(you will have to do this only if you have moved the original object) Just do '1-location(for each axis)' and enter the value. Otherwise skip that node. After this the original ground object and these instances are simply joined through the join geoetry node). (You have to apply this geometry node modifier on the ground plane)